# Syntax error with typename and scope operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Can someone tell me how to fix the syntax problem below?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Thing { 
    static const int num = N;
};

template <int N>
struct Get {
    using type = Thing<N>;
};

template <int... Is>
void foo() {
//  int a[] = {(std::cout << Thing<Is>::num << '\n', 0)...};  // This compiles.
    int a[] = {(std::cout << typename Get<Is>::type::num << '\n', 0)...};  // This does not.
}

int main() {
    foo<0,1,2>();
}
```

GCC 5.1.0 says [Error] expected '(' before '<<' token.  Any quick way to fix this (without writing a new function and have it called within foo)?

Comment: Sure. Get rid of `typename`. You're not accessing a nested type, but a value

Comment: Ah!  So simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Because then a compiler thinks that `num` is a type name, but it's not valid to put a type name in an expression like you did

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Dude. Answers belong in the answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, you don't need `typename` here. But to explain in a bit more detail:

You probably wrote `typename Get<Is>::type::num` because you knew that if you would refer to `Get<Is>::type`, you would need to put `typename` in front of it. That's generally true, but not always. In some cases, the syntax already makes it crystal clear that `type` is used as a type, not as an expression, and in that case you don't need `typename`, and in that case you generally *can't* use `typename`.

When you write `Get<Is>::type::num`, `type` is already assumed to be a type. Putting `typename` in front of it indicates that you want `num` to be treated as a type too. You don't, so don't write `typename`.